# Parameterization affecting query optimizer plan on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

Refering to the scenario described on my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276736/how-to-implement-mod-partitioning-on-sql-server-2008-r2):

In a T-SQL script I have the initialization code:

```
declare @DeviceID int
declare @Partition int

set @DeviceID = 4000
set @Partition = 4000 % 250
```

And, if I try the following query, I get partition elimination:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from Devices
where DeviceID = @DeviceID 
and Date_Time >= '2010-02-01' and Date_Time < '2010-03-01'
and Partition = 0
```

But, if I try the following, I don't get partition elimination:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from Devices
where DeviceID = @DeviceID 
and Date_Time >= '2010-02-01' and Date_Time < '2010-03-01'
and Partition = @Partition
```

How am I going to be able to build a stored procedure if I need to explicitly set the partiton value this way?

Comment: Do you have an even distribution of data across all your partitions? If one is significantly bigger than the others, it could throw things off (particularly if the "first" call to the procedure was against that partition). Even so it is strange, as I've used a similar partitioning scheme (flat integers of varrying sizes), use @Params, and have always seen suitable partition filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query plan is generated based on the entire of the procedure and prior to any execution - the plan engine and execution engine being different entities as such.

So at the time the query plan is being generated, the value of @Partition is unknown (and we assume what you partitioned upon), even though you can see that it represents a deterministic numeric value, the plan engine is not doing the maths to get this literal value at the time of planning the query.

As a result, the query can not partition eliminate, since it does not know which partitions it is eliminating as yet. When you use a literal numeric value, it will show elimination, because no pre-processing is required to compare that against the values for the partitioning.

Comment: That's really a bad thing. I can't expect partition elimination then. I wrote a stored procedure with 250 (there are 250 partition) IF cases, but that was, of course, slow.

Comment: Try pass the value in, both as deviceid and pre-divided in the calling code as a second parameter, instead of doing the mathematics within the code. That should partition eliminate