# SQL Server partitioning vs indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with over 180 million rows.

I have been considering table partitions to reduce the scans (in addition to indexes). One of the columns I've considered to partition by is `STATE`. As this is not a transaction table, I do not have a date column that I desire to partition by. We do not do many selects based on the date.

My question is has anyone ever split their tables on a string-value column instead of a date? And if so, what are the performance considerations for doing so?

Thanks.

Comment: Indexes are probably a better choice for optimization than partitioning.  But, you really need to provide more information about what the queries look like, what the distribution of values by `STATE` is, how often `STATE` is updated, and so on.

Comment: It depends on your workload (queries you run). If you have lots of queries that only ever search on a single state this is fine. If you don't have queries seaching on state, or most of your queries search across many states, this probably won't help. The only reason date is always suggested is because that is quite often a characteristic of the workload, i.e. most people run queries on recent dates. Before adding any indexes you need to understand your workload and take metrics. Also you should consider columnstore indexes also

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can partition alphabetically. Example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59613/partitioning-a-table-state).

But - if the goal is to improve query performance - I'm not sure that table partitioning is going to be the right solution. The primary use for table partitioning is to speed up bulk data loading and archiving.  Remus Rusana - MS SQL Server Developer team member - answered a very [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249073/partitioning-for-query-performance-in-sql-server-2008), a quote ...

> Partitioning is never done for query performance. With partitioning the performance will always be worse, the best you can hope for is no big regression, but never improvement.

And that's from the SQL Server Dev team!  Of course, there may be some *edge* cases where partitioning improves query performance, but this doesn't look like one.

Luckily, we have many options beyond partitioning to improve performance.  Query optimization is a bit of an art, so in order to truly answer your question we'd need many more details.  How wide is the table?  Do you have some example queries?  What is the distribution of data (lumpiness)?

Going only on what you've said - this a not a transaction table - then creating indices sounds like a safe bet.  We can add these without worrying about negatively impacting database DML performance (updates/inserts/deletes).  To start the investigation into what indices to add, Launch SSMS, click the Show Actual Execution Plan button, and execute one of the problematic queries.  Now examine the execution plan.  Please and add any [missing indices](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1945/missing-index-feature-of-sql-server-2008-management-studio/) it finds.  Hope this helps.  Good luck!

**TL:DR Partitioning won't improve query performance, try indexes.**